# Preview window in Android Studio Mac not showing up

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

This question has been asked before but not specifically for the latest version of Android Studio and more specifically for MAC.

I cannot get the Preview mode to show up, neither in the menu through "View / Tool Windows" or in the tool bar.

Are there any known methods to get it visible? I have seen it before but it has now disappeared and won't come back.

Anybody with some tips on how to get it back would be appreciated.

Comment: There are at least three "latest version of Android Studio" versions: 3.6.3, 4.0 Beta 5, and 4.1 Canary 8. What specific version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi and thanks for a quick reply! So Im apparantly using 3.6.3  Build AI 192.7142.36.36.6392135

Comment: Okay, I think I have found it, but its still uncertain. When I have my .xml file selected, just in the top right corner (below the account login, top right corner) there are three small icons, Code | Split | Design,  split is the view I want so now it's there.  Any other routes/paths to secure this would be good to know.

Comment: That's the only path I know of in 3.6.3. If it helps, in 4.0 and higher, those small icons get labels to go with them, as I think Google realized that the icons were... unintuitive.

Comment: Okay, yeah absolutely. Says 3.6.3 is the latest version for Mac right now, unless there is some unstable beta that can be downloaded. But this will do for now. Thanks.